# How does Amazon S3 SLA works with example

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to understand what a `Amazon S3` Service Level Agreement (`SLA`) does. I was able to go through its [documentation found here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/sla/), but still don't seems to understand exactly what it means and what it tries to resolve.

Does it mean that if the up time of a particular service class, lets say `S3 Standard-Infrequent Access` is *Less than 99.0% but greater than or equal to 95.0%*, in a given month, we're suppose to open a ticket and Amazon will compensate us with *25%* ?

Can someone explain SLA with an example to me please ? I am new to AWS.

Comment: For SIA, it's 95%-98%, and be aware that Service Credit is not money back. It's like a promotional credit that can only be used in AWS services.

Comment: @jellycsc Can you check the documentation link above. For SIA is it between 99%-95% or am I looking at the wrong table. Sorry i am a newbie.

Comment: I have another question on the guaranteed 99. (9 x9) durability. Will that also have an impact ?

Comment: Just follow the link you posted in the question, and go to `For requests to S3 Intelligent-Tiering, S3 Standard-Infrequent Access, and S3 One Zone-Infrequent Access:` section. SIA has a different SLA from the Standard storage class.

Comment: Durability is not part of the SLA.

Comment: @jellycsc So SLA is something to do with Availability ? right

Comment: correct, only availability is in the SLA

Comment: Just being curious and not related to SLA. Like Availability, can Durability (the 9, 9s) be impacted and is there a way to compensate it?

Comment: I personally never experienced the durability issue with S3. I guess in the rare event if that happens to you, you will be informed and maybe you can negotiate with them to get compensated if it's something major.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLA may depend on different metrics such as availability, response time of opened tickets etc. It's an agreement between provider and customer. AWS's SLA for S3 is availability.

The next paragraph is taken from [faq section](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)

> The S3 Standard storage class is designed for 99.99% availability, the S3 Standard-IA storage class is designed for 99.9% availability, the S3 One Zone-IA storage class is designed for 99.5% availability, and the S3 Glacier and S3 Glacier Deep Archive class are designed for 99.99% availability and SLA of 99.9%. All of these storage classes are backed by the Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement.

Which means AWS guarantees that it is going to be 99.9 uptime for `S3 Standard-IA storage`. Any number less that number in your billing cycle means that AWS didn't fulfill their commitment(in the defined levels and boundaries).

If you paid $100 in your billing cycle for `S3 Standard-IA storage` and the service's total uptime(in that billing cycle) is 98%, then you will get credit of $10 to be used in AWS services.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is some kind of incoherence on AWS SLA for S3 :

- Technically, S3 Standard is build for 99.99% of SLA

  https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/?nc1=h_ls (as seen in febr2023)

  *S3 Standard : Designed for 99.99% availability over a given year*
- But from a commercial/credit point of view, you will have a refund only if SLA is < 99.9%
  https://aws.amazon.com/s3/sla/?nc1=h_ls (5may2022)

  *S3 Standard : Monthly Uptime Percentage = Less than 99.9% but greater than or equal to 99.0%   => Service Credit Percentage =  10%*